# Internal Server Error when posting variables to Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I posted a similar post earlier and got some great answers but I accidentally removed my post, so I'm posting a revised version with some more data.

I'm building a Web API to post and get data from my views. Communicating with the API works well, but I've run into a problem.

Whenever I send data with my post requests, I get a 500: Internal Server Error. If I remove the data from the request, it works fine.

Example method that works:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Test()
{
    return "this works";
}
```

as I'm not passing any data into the above method I'm not running into any issues. But, whenever I add some data to my request, like so:

API method:

```
[HttpPost]

public string TestWithVariables(string test)
{
    return test;
}
```

AJAX call:

```
 $.post({
        url: myUrl + "/api/my-api/TestWithVariables",
        data: { test: "123456" },
        success: function (html) {
            console.log("y")
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("n");
        }
    });
```

The code above outputs these errors in my browser: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error and XML Parsing Error: Root element not found. Thing is, if I set a break point on the first row of the API method it never gets hit, meaning that the method isn't found, or executed for some reason...?

Some stuff I've tried: breaking my parameter out to a TestClass and using `[FromBody]`. I've also tried using `[FromUri]`, which actually makes the method execute, but I can't access the values from there as my values are posted in the body.

Any ideas what could be causing these problems?

Comment: Are your routes properly defined?

Comment: Routes are all good - if I strip the methods off parameters they are executed.

Comment: Use data as : JSON.Stringify({ test: "123456" });

Answer (score 1):

several things you can do, first make sure you set the content type of the request to be json, by default it will be xml if you don't.

You could also remove the xml formatter completely if you don't need it.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.Clear();
            config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        }
    }
```

This class lives in App_Start.

Either way make sure the content type is set correctly.

Finally make sure you stringify the data before sending it:

```
var model = JSON.stringify({ test: "123456" });

$.post({
        url: myUrl + "/api/my-api/TestWithVariables",
        data: model,
        success: function (html) {
            console.log("y")
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("n");
        }
    });
```

If you still can't hit the controller correctly then check your routes.

Start with a POST method with no parameters. Once you can hit it, add a parameter to it and add a [FromBody] attribute with it.

If you get a 500 error that means you have an internal error somewhere. Put a breakpoint in your method to see if you hit it.

Now, about the routes. Let's say your controller is called SomeController

Your route would become /Some/method name.
You can use the RoutePrefix attribute on the controller and Route attribute on the method to control your route completely.

To be honest I wouldn't have a route like this : /api/my-api/

Yes it's an api and it's yours no need to put that in the route.

So set your RoutePrefix to be api and your Route on the method to be test-param then your url becomes: /api/test-param for example

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class TestController : ApiController

    [HttpPost]
    Route["test-param"]
    public string TestWithVariables([FromBody] string test)
    {
        return test;
    }
```

then your js:

```
var model = JSON.stringify({ test: "123456" });

$.post({
        url: myUrl + "/api/test-param",
        data: model,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (html) {
            console.log("y")
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("n");
        }
    });
```

I am not sure about the correct syntax for contentType but it should be close enough I'd think.

For error handling I personally like Elmah, once configured it logs all exceptions and you can simply call your url/elmad.axd and see all errors nicely reported.

One last thing, it is a good idea to use a nice client when building APIs. My preference goes to Postman as it allows you to easily craft whatever request you need. Once you get everything working in Postman then you can simply build that request in Javascript.

Comment: what is special in your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I now use JSON.stringify before I pass the data, but I'm still getting the same error. I also added JSON formatter to `WebApiConfig`, but that didn't help out either. Are there any other possible issues?

Comment: added more details

Comment: Thanks man. I restructured my routes to your much cleaner approach. But, I'm still not finding the method. After setting up the new routes I:

Posted to the method with no parameters -- this worked. After that, I posted to it WITH a parameter, and I instantly get the Internal Server Error 500, even when trying with [FromBody]. I have a breakpoint on the first line of the method, but it's not getting hit, so the method is not even getting executed...

Comment: any details in the error message other than the 500 code?

Comment: I cant find any. Is there any way to log to my browser, from the webconfig? I've tried a few ways but it seems I'm messing up the logging.

Comment: added details on Elmah as well. This will take a bit of time to configure but it's well worth it.

Comment: Will try Elmah. A question, in my chrome dev tools I can see that in my  request header I have this: `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`. Maybe there's an issue in setting the `Accept` to `application/json`? I tried setting `accepts: application/json` in my `$.post` but that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

as per your provided data the possible issue could be:
you are not using stringify to convert you data to string json in ajax request.
use following

data:JSON.stringify({ test: "123456" });

If it doesn't work than share you controller and other data you can share.

Comment: or send full url.... myUrl + "/api/my-api/TestWithVariables" and controller + authorize attribute on class if any.

Comment: Thanks! I now stringify my data before I post it, but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: @maskinen999 can you give a try to 

[allowanonymous] attribute on you action method

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string TestWithVariables([FromBody]string test) // added FromBody 
{
return test;
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.post({
    url: myUrl + "/api/my-api/TestWithVariables",
    data: { test: "=123456" }, //prefix data with = sign
    success: function (html) {
        console.log("y")
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("n");
    }
});
```